# Placing points on top of an image with HTML/Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to find some code or a technique to place points on top of an image in HTML. When the user clicks on the image, javascript event calls a function with the x,y positions of the pointer relative to the origin of the image. Ideally, the user would also be able to zoom in/out on bigger images that can't fit on the page.

Thanks for any help/ideas!

Comment: Let me get this straight, you want to somehow display a (colored?) point at the location of the mouse pointer when the user clicks on an image?

Comment: downvoting, I just can't Imagine things, provide the code that you're upto... kidding +1 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you should look into HTML5, particularly the Canvas element:

Here are some resources:

- [Reference Documentation](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html)
- [How to draw with HTML5 Canvas](http://thinkvitamin.com/code/how-to-draw-with-html-5-canvas/)
- [Lets call it a drawing surface](http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html)

Comment: Canvas might be overkill in this case. Perhaps it's easier just to clone some predefined "point" image and attach it to the target (x, y set via CSS).

Comment: Hmm the CSS idea looks good. Canvas might work too.. Thanks guys